# Loading data into slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm trying to use this loading pattern which I found here in SO:
[Load slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362253/best-way-to-load-data-into-slickgrid)

That being said, I'm having some troubles to actually display the grid.
I keep getting "uncaught ReferenceError:loadGrid is not defined". I'm not sure about the options var, I suspect that I'm initializing it incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
   function loadGrid () {
    var data =  [
        ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02,  0.03,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42,  1.47,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28,  0.34,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['American International Group, Inc.',  64.13, 0.31,  0.49,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['AT&T Inc.',                           31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Boeing Co.',                          75.43, 0.53,  0.71,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Caterpillar Inc.',                    67.27, 0.92,  1.39,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Citigroup, Inc.',                     49.37, 0.02,  0.04,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company', 40.48, 0.51,  1.28,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Exxon Mobil Corp',                    68.1,  -0.43, -0.64, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['General Electric Company',            34.14, -0.08, -0.23, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['General Motors Corporation',          30.27, 1.09,  3.74,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Hewlett-Packard Co.',                 36.53, -0.03, -0.08, '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Honeywell Intl Inc',                  38.77, 0.05,  0.13,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Intel Corporation',                   19.88, 0.31,  1.58,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['International Business Machines',     81.41, 0.44,  0.54,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Johnson & Johnson',                   64.72, 0.06,  0.09,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co',              45.73, 0.07,  0.15,  '9/1 12:00am'],

    ];

    var options = {'autoHeight:true'};
    var columns = ['company','price','change','pctChange','lastChange'];
    var grid;
    // ... code to get data

    // ... code to get column data/settings

    // ... code to get option data

    $(function () {
    if (grid) {
    grid.setOptions(options);
    grid.setColumns(columns);
    grid.setData(data);
    grid.render();
        } else {
        grid = new Slick.Grid('#trade-reg-trade-info-table', data, columns,options);

                }

     $('#trade-reg-trade-info-table').show();   
    });
    }
```

Thanks for that, now I've corrected it and I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
new Slick.Grid('#trade-reg-trade-info-table"
```

You opened with a single quote and tried closing with a double quote.

```
{
  'company':    'JP Morgan & Chase & Co',
  'price':      45.73,
  'change':     0.07,
  'pctChange':  0.15,
  'lastChange': '9/1 12:00am'
}
```

Comment: I've got it "working" or kind of. The options array elements must not be surrounded by quotes and the columns have to be something like this: {id:"cpny", name:"Company", field:"cpny", width: 18,}. I still can't display my data array though, the columns headers appear completely over width.

Comment: Your `data` variable should be an Array of *Objects*, not an Array of Arrays. I've edited my answer to show you how a single item in your `data` array should look.

Comment: And you're correct about the `columns` array, it should also be an Array of Objects, not an Array of Strings. The strings you currently have in the `columns` array would be the `field` property inside the column object.

Comment: @ idbhold Thanks for that. I've managed to get the whole thing working now.